# Search for substring in csv file row and print the row

Tags: python-3.x

relatively new to python.

I am trying to search for substring in a csv file row and manipulate the data.

**CsvFile:**
Appname1,-l Licensename 1
Appname2,-l Licensename 2
Appname3,-l Licensename 3

I have tried this:

```
def fun(args):
    appNames = args
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('AppNames.csv', "rb"), delimiter=",")
    for row in csv_file:
                #if current rows 2nd value is equal to input, print that row
        if appNames == row[0]:
            print row
        else:
            print "no match found"
```

**Input**: name1

**Expectedoutput**: Appname1,-l Licensename 1

**Currentoutput** : no match or getting error: "TypeError: expected str, bytearray or other buffer compatible object"

However I cant find this still as it is a substring that I am providing.

I tried

```
if appNames in row[1]:
```

But getting error: *"TypeError: expected str, bytearray or other buffer compatible object"*

Anyone has any better ideas how to search for it.

Also I want to copy only the Licensename field to a variable after finding the app name.

Comment: Providing your *exact* inputs and expected vs. actual outputs would make your question more clear.

Comment: ok i have just added input, expectedoutput and currentoutput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are not clear, but don't open in binary mode.  You want to read text strings not byte strings.  Use `newline=''` per csv documentation as well:

```
with open('AppNames.csv',newline='') as file:
    for row in csv.reader(file):
        ...
```

If you are looking for a substring, use `in`:

```
if appName in row[0]:
    ...
```

### Full example returning the license name portion on a match:

input.csv:

```
Appname1,-l Licensename 1
Appname2,-l Licensename 2
Appname3,-l Licensename 3
```

code:

```
import csv

def fun(arg):
    with open('input.csv',newline='') as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            if arg in row[0]:
                return row[1]
    return None

print(fun('name1'))
print(fun('name4'))
```

Output:

```
-l Licensename 1
None
```

Comment: I tried this solution , however it still does not seem to be able to find it in the csv file. this is the code currently:     
    with open('AppNames.csv',newline='') as file:
  for row in csv.reader(file):
   if appNames in row[0]:
    print row
   else:
    print "no match found"

Comment: I am still getting :TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @gadgetor You tagged the question `python-3.x`, but Python 2 doesn't have the newline keyword.  I also noticed your `print` use is as a keyword not a function, which is also Python 2.  make sure you are running Python 3...Python 2 is no longer supported.

Comment: oops sorry mate my bad.